# How to iterate through a string by word, and then through those words using different delimeters (in bash)

Tags: bash

If I have the following string:

```
1234-56-78 17:38:00,00 [main]
```

and I want to isolate the second 'word',

```
17:38:00,00
```

and then parse this word (clearly a time stamp) to isolate each the 17 and the 38 and put them out to variables, how can I do this? I've tried the following, in getting the hour:

```
stampLine="1234-56-78 17:38:00,00 [main]"
array=("$stampLine")
fullStamp=${array[1]}
IFS=':' read -ra splitStamp <<< $fullStamp
stampArray=($splitStamp)
x=${stampArray[0]}
echo ${x#0} # to strip leading zeroes
```

as well as:

```
declare -i index
for item in $array; do
  if [ index == 1 ]; then
    fullStamp=$item
    IFS=':' read -ra splitStamp <<< $fullStamp
    stampArray=($splitStamp)
    x=${stampArray[0]}
    echo ${x#0} # to strip leading zeroes
  fi
done
```

but both of them have failed, which brings me here. If someone could answer this and/or explain what I'm missing, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Related reading http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it unnecessarily complex. This should be sufficient:

```
stampLine="1234-56-78 17:38:00,00 [main]"
read date time tag <<< "${stampLine}"
IFS=: read hours minutes seconds <<< "${time}"
echo ${hours}
echo ${minutes}
```

And, of course, if you wanted to do it in just one step, this would work, because `IFS` is a set of characters for word splitting, not just a single character:

```
IFS=" -:" read x x x hours minutes x <<< "${stampLine}"
```

If you actually cared about the other values, then using other variables in their places would be required, but if you don't, letting the shell re-use a "dummy" variable is useful...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll rework my solution now for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

This fragment of your your first attempt:

> ```
> stampLine="1234-56-78 17:38:00,00 [main]"
> array=("$stampLine")
> ```

... does not do what you want because you have quoted the expansion of `$stampLine`, thereby preventing the expansion from being subject to word splitting.  If you remove the quotes in the second line (and if `$IFS` has a suitable value, such as its default value), then `$array` will be initialized as a three-element array.

Here:

> ```
> fullStamp=${array[1]}
> IFS=':' read -ra splitStamp <<< $fullStamp
> ```

... it's rather heavyweight to use the `read` built-in and a here-string.  I suppose the point is to localize the modified value of `$IFS`, but you could do that other ways.  For example, you could save the original value in a different variable and afterward restore it.  Personally, though, I might be inclined to declare a function with a `local` copy of `$IFS`:

```
split_HMS() {
  local IFS=':'
  splitStamp=($1)
}

# ...

fullStamp=${array[1]}
split_HMS $fullStamp
```

Your second example suffers from the additional problem that although you declare variable `$index`, you never assign any value to it.  As a result, the test `[ $index == 1 ]` will never succeed.

Specifically in response to your question,

> [How can] I want to isolate the second 'word' [...] and then parse
>   this word (clearly a time stamp) to isolate each the 17 and the 38 and
>   put them out to variables [...]?

I might assemble the pieces this way:

```
parseTime() {
  local IFS=':'
  local hms=($2)
  hour=${hms[0]#0}
  minute=${hms[1]#0}
}

stampLine="1234-56-78 17:08:00,00 [main]"
parseTime $stampLine

echo "hour:   $hour"
echo "minute: $minute"
```

Output:

```
hour:   17
minute: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37575969/1765658) of [twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg), I would suggest this:

#### Short way

```
stampLine="1234-56-78 17:38:00,00 [main]"
IFS=$' \n\t:' read day hre min sec foo <<<"$stampLine"

echo $day
1234-56-78
echo $hre
17
echo $min
38
echo $sec
00,00
echo $foo
[main]
```

of course at second line, `IFS` could be `=' :'`, but I prefer this to avoid leading *newline* or unwanted *tab* that could make `read` work wrong.

#### Step detail way

```
stampLine="1234-56-78 17:38:00,00 [main]"
read date time foo <<<$stampLine
IFS=:, read hrs min sec frac <<<$time

echo $foo
[main]
echo $time
17:38:00,00
echo $frac
00
echo $sec 
00
echo $min
38
echo $hrs
17
```

#### One word about *bash regex*

For this kind of usage, having two successives `read`, like in second sample,  will work a lot quicker than using `[[ "$stampLine" =~ ... ]]` [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *regex*...

...or even three successives `read`, with `IFS=- read year month day <<<$date`, will stay *quicker* or *less CPU heater* then using *bash's regexes*.

Comment: Note: There is no quotes, nor double quotes in second sample! I'we keeped them in 1st sample in the meaning of a file reading loop.